# Do I need to have my tax returns attested before immigrating to the US on an L-1B visa?

Tags: united-states, taxes, india

I am a citizen of India and have my L-1B visa approved. I wanted to know if after L-1/H-1 visa is approved, before moving to the US, do we need to get our previous years IT returns attested at the collectorate office? Is it a smooth process or does it take time?

Answer (score 1):

> I wanted to know if after L-1/H-1 visa is approved, before moving to the US, do we need to get our previous years IT returns attested at the collectorate office?

This is no longer required. In past quite a few Indians were moving out of country without paying the taxes due and hence there was a scrutiny. As all of this is now automated, best you carry the soft copies. Haven't heard anyone being asked for this for quite sometime now.